# How to display GAME OVER screen and YOU WIN screen in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a GAME OVER screen that is functioning when your health is depleted. This GAME OVER screen is executed with the show_go_screen. I tried to just duplicate the method for the show_go_screen into my show_winning() function for the other screen. I rigged this show winning function by setting your health back to normal when going back to the game. However once you have gone to the YOU WIN screen and back to the game you cannot go to the YOU WIN screen again. I have included the code for my player shield below (which determine when there is a GAME OVER/YOUWIN event) I have also included the methods for the show_go_screen (which is for GAME OVER) and the code for show_winning() method (which is for the YOU WIN screen). If someone can tell me how to best modify my code to get the desired result.

```
if TrumpHits:
            self.trump.shield -= 25
        if self.trump.shield <= 0:
            self.show_winning()
            self.winning = True
      if hits:
             self.player.shield -= 20
        if flyby:
             self.player.shield -= 30
        if self.player.shield <= 0:
            self.playing = False
```

## here are the show_go_screen() and the show_winning() methods

```
 def show_go_screen(self):
        # game over/continue
        if not self.running:
            return

        bg = pg.image.load("GAMEOVERslimeCOVERAGE.png")
        self.screen.blit(bg,(0,0))



        self.draw_text("Press space bar to play again", 22, WHITE, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT * 7 / 8)
 HEIGHT / 2 + 40)


        pg.display.flip()
        waiting = True
        while waiting:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    waiting = False
                    self.running = False
                if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                   if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                      waiting = False

                      self.PlayMusic()

    def show_winning(self):
        # game over/continue
        if self.winning:
            return

        bg = pg.image.load("TRUMPyouwin3d.png")
        self.screen.blit(bg,(0,0))



        self.draw_text("Press any key to play again", 22, WHITE, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT * 7 / 8)


        pg.display.flip()

        waiting = True
        while waiting:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    waiting = False
                    self.running = False
                if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                   if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                      waiting = False

                      self.PlayMusic()
                      self.player.shield = 100
                      self.trump.shield = 100


    def wait_for_key(self):
        waiting = True
        while waiting:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    waiting = False
                    self.running = False
                if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                    waiting = False
```

Comment: Don't post your code; create a [mcve] instead. It'll make the question more beneficial for other people as it becomes easier to read, understand, test/verify and it'll also make it easier for the people who are trying to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the player or the enemy have less than zero health, set `self.playing = False` which stops the game's while loop.  Then the `show_go_screen` method of the game instance `g` is called in the outermost while loop.

```
while g.running:
    g.new()
    g.show_go_screen()
```

In the `show_go_screen` method, blit the background image and the text (I created the BACKGROUND_IMG and the FONT object globally), flip the display and start another while loop with an event loop in which you check if the user wants to quit or continue. If the user quits, you set `self.running` to `False` so that the outer while loop will stop as well, because its condition is `while g.running:`. If space is pressed, you can just return from this `show_go_screen` method and the outer while loop calls `g.new()` what resets the game.

```
def show_go_screen(self):
    self.screen.blit(BACKGROUND_IMG, (0, 0))
    text_surface = FONT.render("Press space bar to play again", True, WHITE)
    self.screen.blit(text_surface, (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT * 7 / 8))
    pg.display.flip()
    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.running = False
                done = True
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    done = True

        self.clock.tick(FPS)
```

If you want to make more complex scenes/states, I recommend to use a [finite state machine like this](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/3kghhj/simple_state_machine_example/). It's actually just a scene manager class which allows you to switch between the different scenes/states of the game.